# Running app on all available devices (Android Studio)

Tags: android, sdk, emulation

I have two emulators running and a physical device attached. How to run my app on all three devices?

I saw some answer which include a bash script, but is there a option for this inside Android Studio?

EDIT: I actually found the answer by myself. **Solution is really simple**: when you click on "Run 'app'" just press SHIFT or CTRL to select devices on which you want to emulate. Emulators need to be manually opened before this. Keep in mind that Android Studio need to rebuild each app for each devices, so it will take some time.

Comment: Nope, there isn't any such option in Studio.

Comment: Ok thanks. You could have answered a question, not post a comment :)

Comment: Hehe! I guess I could've but it felt so trivial. :P

Comment: Oh wow! Didn't know **SHIFT** + **LEFT CLICK** works in the `Device Chooser` dialog! :o

Comment: Now you post it as an answer and accept it! :P :D

Comment: But still you'll to launch for emulators separately!

Comment: Yea, you need to launch emulator separately.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Edit configuration in android studio which is near the play button and in deployment target option select show device chooser dialog and click ok.
now click on the play button a dialog ll appear select all the devices together and click ok.